# How to use assert corectly in this function?

Tags: c

I have the following function and I am using `assert` in a couple of places. I want to know where I am using assert in a wrong way and why.  The first one is wrong because we can't use assert on an user input.
The second one: can we use assert to check if `malloc` succeeded?
The rest I still can't figure out why.  Can you give any help?
I would like a short explanation of why `assert` is good or bad in the given places.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define num 10
int hh(char *);
```

Comment: All of your asserts, except 6, are wrong. You do not assert things unless you know that it must be true, because that is what the logic of your code produces. 6 is fine, as long as there are no invocations of `f()` outside of your code. In this case, the logic behind `assert` goes as follows: "I am the one calling `f`, and I always pass non-null. If `null` is seen, the code is broken".

Comment: do you why 6 is coorect ?

Comment: They're all legal code. Your question seems to be about what is recommended practice.  Which depends on who's doing the recommending of course.

Comment: 3 and 4 are redundant and may be removed by the compiler, because the string must be shorter than N unless undefined behaviour has already occurred.  (You should use a limiter in the scanf format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want this answer to provide an alternative view on your assertions, by trying hard to see a meaningful use of the assertion examples. I otherwise agree with the answer(s) which condemns most of them.

Assertions are used to verify assumptions, i.e. to assert that they are true.
Think of an assertion as

- a method of self-documentation, stating
  "In the following code I blindly assume that the following expression is always true. If that is not the case, something outside of my control is very wrong and this code cannot do what it is supposed to do."
  This self documentation always works, wether the assertions are active or not.
- a technical implementation, which, if active, will verify that the expression is true at runtime, or in case of failure will ring an alarm bell;
  i.e. it will use some appropriate method to get the attention of somebody
  (this method of getting attention can vary greatly; on deeply embedded platforms, the method can get very interesting...)
  Note that assertions usually are implemented in a way that can be deactivated.  This serves the purpose of removing their consumption of time, consumption of code size and potential generation of confusing output. Deactivating them is therefor sometimes done before delivering the software, at the end of development/testing. The method of getting attention might not only be unpleasant, it can actually be dangerous. Think of software in a plane, hitting a failed assumption in the air... Horrible and definitly a mistake in the software somewhere. However, in the air, you do not want useful debugging information being conventiently displayed somewhere. You simply want the plane to suck it up and somehow return to normal operation as fast as possible.
  Therefore, the technical implementation part is only useful for problems which occur systematically, i.e. it can be assumed that what can occur in normal use will also occur in the test/development situation. This is the case for most kinds of being misued against specification. This is not the case for transient or rare problems, i.e. problems which occur only in unpredictable situations.

Looking at the assertion examples individually:

1. Blindly assuming that the number of input arguments is 2 seems somewhat daring.
   But if the environment of your program is extremely tightly defined, this is imaginable. Your program might be part of a piping setup or only be called from a makefile. An assertion on the number of input arguments would reflect the larger scope of the architecture and would support error detection in a system which is maintained by a multitude of developers.
   That purpose would however be better served by checking in program code and giving a helpful error message before terminating unsuccessfully.
2. Blindly assuming that malloc does not return zero is a widely spread mistake. Doing that explicity with an assertion, which will at least detect and signal the problem, is actually an improvement on just using malloc without checking. A failure of malloc, caused by system memory being exhausted in an unusual situation, is an example of a problem which cannot usefully be detected with an assertion, i.e. not "systematically", not "misuse against spec".
   Again, checking in program code, with a suitable error message and unsuccessful termiantion, would be better.
3. Blindly assuming a maximum input lenght is daring. What should keep a human from heeding this rule? Especially if there is no output forbidding longer input.
   Like 1, this is imaginable in a tightly defined larger architecture, where humans do not get in the way.
   Again, checking in code with error message would be better, even for a make tool being the user.
4. I agree with John, I simply do not see how this assertion can fail.
   Assertions should decribe assumptions which can actually fail by C syntax and semantic. By contrast, I have seen `assert(false)` more often than I thought possible. That makes at least the sense of "I blindly assume that runtime execution will never ever end up here." but is otherwise very strange and requires an extensive (and usually missing) comment explanation.
5. Another "humans stay out" assumption, which might make sense in context of make.
   Better checked and error-reported at runtime.
6. This is a typical assertion at the start of a function which uses a pointer and relies on a "promise" that it will only be called with non-NULL pointers. So somewhere in the specification, there should be some "This function can only be called with non-NULL pointers.".
   Checking this at runtime with an error message and unsuccessful termination is still sensible, in order to also be robust against NULL pointers when assertions are deactivated. This might however be considered a waste of time and code size; the more so the more expensive both is in comparison to the confidence in code quality, specification honoring and testing depth.

Answer (score 3):

You define what is right and wrong, so it is up to you, but as a general rule you don't want your program logic in asserts (so checking the length of an input string is a poor use).

Just remember: assert is only active in debug mode, and so if you rely on it for error checking (like almost all of your examples), you will have weird things happening in release mode.

i.e. assert is normally a define like:

```
/* assert() only does something if NDEBUG is NOT defined */
#ifdef NDEBUG
#else
#define assert(x) _assert(x)
#endif
```

See [Where does the -DNDEBUG normally come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878645/where-does-the-dndebug-normally-come-from) for more info on NDEBUG

You definitely don't want to change the flow using asserts e.g.

```
assert(some_function()); /* some_function only called if NDEBUG is not defined */
```

Using `assert` to check the return of `malloc`: If NDEBUG is not defined the check is not done, so in theory you can go off and access a NULL pointer. I'd say it is NOT safe. See [Handling error checking with assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486414/handling-error-checking-with-assertfor) more discussion.

Lets look at your asserts one by one through the simple "only in debug" filter:

```
assert(argc==2);
/*
 * If NDEBUG is defined and argc == 1 you get through,
 * so anything that uses argc[1] will give undefined behavior.
 * = BAD USE
 */
 char *s = malloc(N);
 /* 2 */
 assert(s!=NULL);
 scanf("%s", s
 /*
  * If NDEBUG is defined and malloc fails you keep going and read into 
  * NULL = undefined behaviour = BAD
  */

 assert(strlen(s)<N);
 /*
  * If NDEBUG is defined keeps going even in strlen >= N.
  * How bad that is depends on the code - if you are checking the size
  * before putting it in a buffer, then it's bad.
  * To me it is logic in the assert and so I say BAD
  */
 /* 4 */
 assert(!*(s+strlen(s)));
 /*
  * First of that's just silly code.
  * If that comes to my code review you'll be removing or rewriting
  * it - strlen relies on the NUL, so how can it fail?
  * It is logic in the assert - If NDEBUG is set you'll keep going
  * even if the condition is not met. How bad that is?
  */
 /* 5 */
 assert(atol(s));
 /*
  * Whoa. If NDEBUG is set and s = "Hello" we still keep going...
  * What is atol("Hello") ?
  */
 printf("%ld\n", 100000000/atol(s));
 free(s);
 return 0;
}
int f(char *s)
{
 /* 6 */
 assert(s!=NULL);
 /*
  * Again if NDEBUG is defined the check disappears and so if s = NULL 
  * then you dereference a NULL pointer which is undefined behavior
  */
 return !*s;
```

Comment: ok so 1 ,3,4,5 are all wrong because it is not good to check with assert an input that came from a user ,, but 2 why it is wrong ?

Comment: or maybe 2 is not wrong i am not sure about this one

Comment: ןi mean 1,2 not coreect because the input comes from the user ! the rest i didn't really get it :\

Comment: do you know why 6 is ok to use assert ?

Comment: On reflection after the analysis above, all your usages (including 6) are wrong.

Comment: WOW ! you know this wasn't wrote by me but i was asked to check where assert was used good and where not ! and i thought 6 was good :/ why is it bad here ! i am confused

Comment: what do you mean by release mode ?

Comment: As a thought experiment: remove all the `asserts` - that is how you code looks in release mode. Now look for all the possible errors. If there are none then your asserts were ok. If the "new" code can have errors then the asserts are probably bad. I'll edit about assert and debug/release modes.

Comment: Note that the C standard requires `#define NDEBUG` or equivalent to be in effect to suppress `assert`; otherwise, assertions are active.  And, moreover, the state of `NDEBUG` is tested anew each time the header is included, so you can have some parts of a file compiled with active assertions and other parts with inactive assertions if you include `<assert.h>` multiple times and change the definedness of `NDEBUG` between the inclusions.

Comment: but isn't this the point of assert is to correct me from doing something wrong ? so why do you compare it with release mode ???

Comment: Assertions should fail if the code is broken (their failures lead to crashes in debug mode), not if input is invalid (you don't guarantee that checks are in place). Assertions are good if you believe that in one place it is impossible otherwise and you assume that (so in debug mode it crashes if your assumption is wrong)